# Unexpected side effect setting point colors in chart xAxis

Tags: c#, charts

I am using `point.IsEmpty` to hide certain points in a chart (outliers). I have this working well, but I noticed something strange. If I restore the chart colors then when the point is hidden or unhidden it shows up at a different location. I don't even have to restore the color; if I simply fetch and store the same color value, the side effect occurs.

```
Color c = SavedColoredPoints[i].Color;;

foreach (DataPoint p in ChartScatter.Series[i].Points)
{
    Debug.Assert(!p.Color.IsEmpty);  // want to show all have been initialized 
    Color ThisC = p.Color;
    p.Color = ThisC;
    // p.Color = c;
}

ChartScatter.Series[i].Color = c;
```

The above code when run does not assert as all the colors are initialized.
When searching online for problems setting color into points, I found the suggestion to use transparent for empty points which I did for all my series. It had no effect.

```
ChartScatter.Series[seriesname].EmptyPointStyle.Color = Color.Transparent;
```

I also read this old blog at Microsoft about setting point colors: 
[Setting Microsoft Chart Series Colors](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alexgor/2009/10/06/setting-microsoft-chart-series-colors)

Example of problem: There are 12 points in one series. If I mark all 12 points "IsEmpty" they will show up on the chart. If I do not restore the default colors the points remain hidden like they are supposed to:

[image: RedDots]

The red points above are not supposed to be there. If I "hide" the original points they tend to show up very near where they were deleted. They actually disappear but instantly are adjacent or above like magic. When the last of the 12 is hidden "IsEmpty" then all 12 show up around the 60 sec marker. The x and y values are all correct but they should be hidden. OTOH if I have not "restored the default colors" then as I unhide them they stay hidden and the chart behaves like I want it.

Comment: Has the Series IsXValueIndexed ? How do you add the points?

Comment: Not doing any out of the ordinary, no indexing.  If this problem has never been seen before I could put a test program together to confirm the "bug" or "feature" and submit it.

Comment: ~~~
ChartScatter.Series[seriesname].Points.DataBindXY(xAxis.ToArray(), yAxis.ToArray());
~~~

Comment: OK, wrote a small (?) program and was able to duplicate the condition.  I do not see how to add code samples to a comment.  I zipped up the demo and put it at https://stateson.net/images/TestChart.zip  The hide and unhide work perfectly right up until the color is changed then all H..L happens that I cannot account for.  To see the problem click on hide / unhide a few times then enable random colors.  thank you for looking at this.

Comment: Got it; looks quite interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This certainly **looks** like a bug in  MSChart.

**But** if you look at it right, there may be a certain logic behind it.

What seems to be happening is this: The chart displays a `empty DataPoints` not with their actual y-values but with the one of the **last non-empty** point before them.

The result looks silly, so in your case it works as a bug. Otoh, the way you are using the `IsEmpty` property is **not** what is **meant** for: It is meant to mark some parts of the data as 'missing'; therefore it assumes that those points do not have a **valid** y-value anyway. But for many chart types this could lead to weird results, so **it carries over the last valid value**..

A classic example are charts with daily data but without meaningful data on the weekends. If the missing data are left out some things will not work, so empty dummy points are inserted. (In fact there is even a function to do that.)

(Note that this is just my interpretation, not a documented feature!)

This wouldn't result in the funny display you see, as you have set the `EmptyPointStyle.Color`to `Transparent`. But: Now you change the colors for **all points** and this **overrides** the color from the series style and voila: Funny display..:

[image]

Solution:

- You could add a line of code to the `Rescale` function to make the points `Transparent` again on an individual basis and then call it from the `UnHide` code. (*)
- Or you could stop (ab)using the `IsEmpty` property altogether and 'hide' points directly by setting their Color to Transparent.

(*) Also note the quote from your link: *You can always switch back to using the palette colors by setting (both Series and) DataPoint Color properties to Color.Empty.* (My parenthesis)

**Update (*):** I think the best way to do the coloring is to include a check for the `IsEmpty` property like this:

```
if (p.IsEmpty)  p.Color = Color.Empty;
else ..
```

Comment: I will try both as I need to hide outliers in my statistics display.  However, I did updated the program to show the side effect better.  I removed the setting for transparent style to show that had no effect and also simply did a fetch and store to show merely accessing the the color triggers the unwanted behavior.  Strange - I removed a left over test program from the zip but when I rezipped the size was 6x bigger.

Comment: OK, will try that also.  The idea of using Transparency instead of empty did not work.  was even stranger behavior.  Points were hidden ok, but did not unhide until I tried hiding (they were all still hidden) then they all showed up all at once except the point I had just hidden.  I am including 2 before an after links to my actual program to show how the outlier at grid 1.0 days totally messes the display.  http://stateson.net/images/beforehide.png and http://stateson.net/images/afterhide.png

Comment: Hm, not sure I can follow (or quite believe).. - I did work here, but the real program will of course have a more complicated logic..

Comment: The before link seems to show only a single point at the 1.0 day grid.  In actuality there are 844 points all drawn so close to the y-axis at "0.1" that they cannot be seen.  If I increase the size they just show up as a thicker y-axis line.  I assume I could change the y-axis crossing to show there is something there, not sure how that works on a log scale.  The bug manifests itself  when I change the series to show individual series instead of all at once.

Comment: My comment earlier about transparence not working was when I set p.color = transparent to hide a point and then tried p.color = defaultcolor to restore the point.  That caused even worse behavior just by itself, not even doing that "rescaling"

Comment: I just tried that your suggestion of using color.empty  and isempty and it looks like it is working fine.  If you are into "boinc" then my app at GitHub\jstateson might be useful.  How do I credit you for the solution?

Comment: I like that video, thanks for sharing it.  I am pretty sure this is a bug.  I this worth reporting to Microsoft's TechNet?  Also, I was unable to completely solve the problem in my code as one series was made up of 2 ore more sets that each had to have different points colored.  As long as the points were homogenous (one color) there was no problem.  Rebinding the entire series (total radraw) was required but not worth the trouble so I did not restore the original colors.